# Equation of the plane that is at given distances from three given points $A,B,C$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, 3d

Suppose you have the coordinates of three points $A,B,C$.  You want to construct a plane $\pi$ such that

$ d(\pi, A) = r_1 $

$ d(\pi, B) = r_2 $

$ d(\pi , C ) = r_3 $

where $d(\pi,v) $ is the perpendicular distance function, which returns the distance between point $v$ and the plane $\pi$.

What are the conditions on $r_1, r_2, r_3$ so that a solution exists?  And what is the equation of this plane in terms of the coordinates of $A,B,C$ and the values of $r_1, r_2, r_3 $?

**My attempt:**

Starting with the first point $A$, a plane that is $r_1$ away from $A$, must be of the form

$ n \cdot ( r - (A + r_1 n ) ) =  0 \tag{1} $

where $n$ is a unit vector.  The envelope of all such planes is a sphere centered at $A$ and with radius $r_1$.

Applying the second condition, we find that

$ r_2 = | n \cdot ( B - A)  - r_1 | \tag{2}$

And applying the third condition, we get

$ r_3 = | n \cdot (C - A) - r_1 | \tag{3}$

First, let's assume that,

$  | n \cdot(B - A) - r_1 | = n \cdot(B - A) - r_1 \tag{4} $

This implies that

$ n \cdot (B - A) \ge r_1 \tag{5} $

And from $(2)$ and $(4)$,

$ n \cdot (B - A) = r_1 + r_2 \tag{6} $

Since $ n \cdot (B - A) $ is bounded from above by $ \| B - A \| $ and from below by $- \| B - A \| $

Then under the assumption of $(4)$, we must have

$ - \| B - A \| \le r_1 + r_2 \le \| B - A \| \tag{7} $

The left inequality is automatically satisfied because $r_1 + r_2$ is a positive number.

Next, if we assume that

$  | n \cdot(B - A) - r_1 | = r_1 -  n \cdot(B - A)  \tag{8} $

This can only happen if

$ n \cdot (B - A) \lt r_1 \tag{9} $

Now from $(8)$ and $(2)$,

$ n \cdot (B - A) = r_1 - r_2 \tag{10} $

Hence, solutions will exist in this case if and only if

$ - \| B - A \| \le r_1 - r_2 \le \| B - A \| \tag{11}$

Repeating the same steps for point $C$ gives two more conditions:

$ r_1 + r_3 \le \| C - A \| \tag{12} $

$ - \| C - A \| \le r_1 - r_3 \le \| C - A \| \tag{13}$

So we have four cases for the signs of $ ( n \cdot (B - A) - r_1 )$ and $( n \cdot (C - A) - r_1) $.  Taking this cases one by one, and applying the above inequalities, and assuming they are satisfied, then we can have a maximum of $4$ systems of equations, each having two possible solutions.  Therefore a maximum of $8$ distinct planes will solve the problem.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could go over the above analysis, and verify these findings.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your issue boils down to find a plane tangent to 3 spheres with given centers and radii (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/129771/305862)). In this setting, the mutual relations between the coordinates of centers and radii of the spheres for such a plane to exist are very tricky (hopefully more than the conditions you have found).

Comment: This interesting [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2101428/305862) using the powerful tools of Lie sphere geometry is very connected to your question ; it is shown there in particular that (indeed) one can have up to 8 tangent planes to 3 spheres.

Comment: Yes.  It is interesting.  Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Using inversion with respect to one of the spheres would be another option.

Comment: Yes.  It would be really great if you could post an answer to this question using inversion.  I would really appreciate that.  I will certainly upvote it, and I think many other community members would be interested in that too.

Comment: I don't know if I am able to find a solution using inversion. But now that I have seen the nice drawing with 8 tangent planes in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4792332/305862) to a particular case, I realize that the radical center (the point with the same  power wrt to the 3 spheres) can play a role in the classification of the different cases.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2101056/255730